# Are there any proposals from the Turkic countries in Central Asia for becoming a federation?

Tags: federalism

There is an [association of Turkic countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organization_of_Turkic_States) called *Turkic Council*.

Apart from that, are there any proposals from the Turkic countries in Central Asia for becoming a federation?

Related [The Turkic world is on the edge of a historic revival](https://www.trtworld.com/opinion/the-turkic-world-is-on-the-edge-of-a-historic-revival-30327)

Comment: If you exchanged "federation" with a more radical aim to "unite" all Turks, you would come up with the [Grey Wolves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_Wolves_(organization)).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so.

Kazakhstan is the richest one and also only partially located in Central Asia. Also, lots of Russians and Russian speakers.

Turkmenistan. A North Korea-style dictatorship with cash issues. Will not open to anybody.

Uzbekistan. An industrial and demographic power of Central Asia and therefore distrusted by everybody else.

Tajikistan. Not Turkic - a Persian-speaking country. Also very poor.

Kyrgyzstan. Don't know anything about them, frankly.

Some of them actively hate each other to the point of military conflict.

I won't expect any kind of (secular) federation.

Comment: "Kyrgyzstan. Don't know anything about them, frankly." It's probably more useful then to leave that part out of the answer. :)

Comment: I don't think so, at least people now what to google.